# How do I remove hyperlinks from \tableofcontents in beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, links

I am designing a presentation in `beamer` and would like to use `\tableofcontents` to generate an outline frame.  However, by default, `beamer` includes hyperlinks on the section names in the table of contents.  Here is a minimal example of this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Who's on first?}
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{What's on second?}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have found that it is much too easy to accidentally click on one of these hyperlinks while speaking and derail the presentation.  Aside from manually writing a contents frame, how can I remove these hyperlinks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the environment `NoHyper`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{NoHyper}
  \tableofcontents
\end{NoHyper}
\end{frame}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Who's on first?}
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{What's on second?}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `NoHyper` should be included in the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf). If you're interested in stopping the hyperlinking from some point onward, issue `\makeatletter \stop@hyper \makeatother`.

Comment: @Werner: You can find the environment in the [complete hyperref manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf)

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for pointing out the difference between the two manuals.