# Style links differently in references, figures and the table of contents?

Tags: hyperref

Using the hyperref package, I have been able to style and make all my links clickable in my document:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    allcolors  = {blue} %Change to black if we want them invisible
}
```

Using this codes enables me to style and click[1] the 1 in order to navigate to my bibliography. However, I also want my links to my figures to be clickable, so when I write (see table 1) then 1 should be a link to the figure. I also noticed that my styling seem to affect my table of contents, so it is completely blue at the moment.

So I'm wondering how I can apply separate styling to my table of contents and my figures?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For your first question you could use something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28125/how-do-i-remove-hyperlinks-from-tableofcontents-in-beamer, which will remove the hyperlinks from the table of contents, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc, which will keep the links but they will appear black. Your second question (about the figures) is not completely clear: do you want a different color for the figure links, or is the problem that you want links for figure references but they don't appear?

Comment: Thanks! The second link answered my question! Regarding you questions, it's actually both. I want text such as "see figure 2" have the "2" link to the actual figure when pressed. I also want this "2" to be another color than my other links. I don't know how to  create this link or how to color it.

Comment: When you reference a figure with `\ref` (as explained in, e.g., the 2nd link in the answer by @Yappari below) then a hyperlink is created automatically - if it is not, then please provide a small example document that reproduces the problem. With the `hyperref` package you can also use `\autoref` instead of `\ref`, which will add the word _Figure_ before the number (and this word will also be part of the link).

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options for coloring links, e.g. allcolors, citecolor, linkcolor.

Your **ToC** becomes blue because you have specified `allcolors` to be blue.

> **allcolors** set all color options (without border and
>   field options)

To color the ToC links you can use [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc).

When referencing figures, are you asking specifically how to [reference figures in text](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Referencing_Figures) and/or hyperlink them? This option is defined in the hyperref package too:

> **hyperfigures** make figures hyper links

For future references and guides I recommend checking on sites like [ShareLateX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) or other LaTeX [wiki:s](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) if not [the package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) in question where you can find a summary of all the different [hyperref options;](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/options.pdf).